# Debian 9 (Stretch)-based OS, PHP Ver. 8.0.14 on Openlitespeed, lsphp80-redis extension problem

Tags: wordpress, redis, debian, php-8, openlitespeed

After command:
apt-get install lsphp80 lsphp80-common lsphp80-mysql lsphp80-memcached lsphp80-redis lsphp80-opcache lsphp80-curl lsphp80-imagick -y (https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/wordpress/)
everything okey except system can't find lsphp80-redis module to install it. I can't fully use LiteSpeed plugin options in WP (need enable redis cache in admin panel for it after).

Comment: probably because it doesn't have , you can try to compile it

Comment: most likely - it doesn't exists yet, not so long ago same problem was with another ones 8.0.. extensions. Today for ex. lsphp74-redis have no prob..

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem a few days ago and actually answered it here: [OpenLiteSpeed how enable php module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850864/openlitespeed-how-enable-php-module/71181101#71181101)
But to summarize: lsphp80-redis is supposed to be in the repo but got forgotten for some reason (in my case it was lsphp74-redis, but nevermind).

The solution is to install the LiteSpeed pear extension from the LiteSpeed repos and then use pecl to install Redis. They explain it here: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/extapp/php/extensions/

The commands you would need are:

```
apt install lsphp74-pear
```

followed by

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/bin/pecl install resdis
```

Don't forget to make a `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp80/etc/php/8.0/mods-available/redis.ini` with something like this:

```
; configuration for php redis
; priority=20
extension=redis.so
```

They give instructions for Redhat and Ubuntu/Debian in the link.

I also prefer the binary packages for easy maintenance but this works.